# React Search Bar , call function from another class

Tags: django, reactjs

hello guys i am fetching data from my api and i try to set a search bar like this :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ProductsIndex from "./search_bar";

class SearchBar extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = { term: "" };

  this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
}

onInputChange(event) {
 this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
}

onFormSubmit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();


ProductsIndex.renderProducts(this.state.term)
// this.props.fetchWeather(this.state.term);
this.setState({ term: "" });
}

render() {
 return (
  <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="input-group">
    <input
      placeholder="Get a five-day forecast in your favorite cities"
      className="form-control"
      value={this.state.term}
      onChange={this.onInputChange}
    />
    <span className="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
    </span>
  </form>
  );
 }
}
export default SearchBar;
```

In my onSubmit function  try to call my function renderProducts from my class ProductsIndex here :

```
class ProductsIndex extends Component {
 componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchProducts();
}

renderProducts(term) {
 return _.map(this.props.products, product => {

  if(product.name==term) {

  return (
    <tr key={product.name}>
        <td>{product.name}</td>
        <td>{product.product_category.name}</td>
        <td>{product.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
}

});
}

render(){

 return(
  <div>
    <table className="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.renderProducts()}
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
);
 }
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {products: state.products}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchProducts}) 
(ProductsIndex);
```

But that is doesn't work i get this error : Uncaught TypeError: _search_bar2.default.renderProducts is not a function
Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: `ProductsIndex.prototype.renderProducts`

The correct answer is: the state of terms should be owned by a component higher up in the hierarchy. SearchBar triggers a state change in the parent component and it trickles down to ProductIndex. You already probably have a component suitable for this in your hierarchy, but here is how it may look if you add one explicitly for this purpose.

```
export class SharedParent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            term: ""
        };

        //I use this style for methods, you can also use fat arrows to ensure 'this' is properly set
        this.setTerm = this.setTerm.bind(this);
    }

    setTerm(term) {
        //beware current best practice is to pass a fucntion
        //not an object to setState
        this.setState({ term });
    }

    render() {
        return [
            <ProductIndex key="a" term={this.state.term} {...this.props.productProps} />,
            <SearchBar key="b" setTerm={this.setTerm}  {...this.props.searchProps}/>
        ];
    }
}
```

PS: I would suggest also using Redux or another state management solution. You can't go wrong with Redux though.

Comment: i replace renderProducts by function Products(props) and "ProductsIndex.prototype.renderProducts but i get error Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (18:11) and BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (18:11) at function Products

Comment: Sorry, I had not quite understood what you were trying to do. I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: I don't understand your anwser , my question is how can i call my function in another class ?

Comment: Can you back-track and tell me what you want to do in term of UI, not of classes?     What I understand, is you want the ProducIndex component to update when you search for a different term. Correct? The way to do this, is to have that term live in the state of a component that's higher up the hierarchy than both ProductIndex and SearchBar, and to pass a method to SearchBar that alters that component's state.

What you are trying to do (call a `class` method directly inside another class) is not the way to do it. Do not do that.

Comment: yes , i sucess to fetch my data from my api and display it into table , i want now add a search bar to display just objects with the input value of the user , can you plz tell me what the way to do that ?

Comment: Well, if you want the `ProductIndex` to be aware of the term entered into the search bar, they have to share access to a property(let's say `term`). If you see my example above, the `SharedParent` component has a state property called "term" which it passes down to `ProductIndex`, and a setTerm function that modifies the term state property. That function gets passed to `SearchBar`, which can now call it to update `ShareParent`'s state. Once the state of `SharedParent` changes, the chagne trickles down to `ProductIndex`. Does that make sense?